# Oracle SQL select 1000 rows at a time out of a hundred thousand rows

Tags: java, mysql, oracle

I have a table with approx. 150 thousand rows and I have to fetch 1000 rows at a time using Java Quartz Scheduler. The requirement is to limit 1000 rows at a time then next 1000 rows etc.(Same as MySQL limit query).

I'm using following query:

```
select * from ( select a.*, rownum rnum from (SELECT a.product_id as productId, 
p.project_id as projectId from <TABLE-1> a INNER JOIN <TABLE-2> p 
ON p.product_id = a.product_id ORDER BY a.product_id ) 
a where rownum <= 1000) where rnum >= 1;
```

The issue is the above query is returning extra column rownum which I don't need in the resultset because the returned data is passed to MapListHandler() which in return convert result to JSON and I'm passing this JSON to a webservice which is not expecting extra rownum column.\

**Database Oracle 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0**

Comment: What happens if you just select the columns that the web service is expecting?

Comment: Yes its working on Oracle DB but from Java scheduler getting error. The answer below is working. See my comment that I have updated the query that you are suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use * in select clause. It should work.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. New Query is like:
select productId, project_id from ( select a.*, rownum rnum from (SELECT a.product_id as productId, 
p.project_id as projectId from <TABLE-1> a INNER JOIN <TABLE-2> p 
ON p.product_id = a.product_id ORDER BY a.product_id ) 
a where rownum <= 1000) where rnum >= 1;